# Python Pandas - Merge based on substring in string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with the following format:

```
df_search

SEARCH
part1
anotherpart
onemorepart


df_all

FILE             EXTENSION    PATH
part1_1         .prt    //server/folder1/part1_1
part1_2         .prt    //server/folder2/part1_2
part1_2         .pdf    //server/folder3/part1_2
part1_3         .prt    //server/folder2/part1_3
anotherpart_1   .prt    //server/folder1/anotherpart_1
anotherpart_2   .prt    //server/folder3/anotherpart_2
anotherpart_3   .prt    //server/folder2/anotherpart_3
anotherpart_3   .cgm    //server/folder1/anotherpart_3
anotherpart_4   .prt    //server/folder3/anotherpart_4
onemorepart_1   .prt    //server/folder2/onemorepart_1
onemorepart_2   .prt    //server/folder1/onemorepart_2
onemorepart_2   .dwg    //server/folder2/onemorepart_2
onemorepart_3   .prt    //server/folder1/onemorepart_3
onemorepart_4   .prt    //server/folder1/onemorepart_4
```

The full df_search has 15,000 items. df_all has 550,000 items. I am trying to merge the two dataframes based on the search item string being in the file string. My desired output is this:

```
SEARCH       FILE            EXTENSION  PATH    
part1        part1_1        .prt    //server/folder1/part1_1    
part1        part1_2        .prt    //server/folder2/part1_2    
part1        part1_2        .pdf    //server/folder3/part1_2    
part1        part1_3        .prt    //server/folder2/part1_3    
anotherpart anotherpart_1   .prt    //server/folder1/anotherpart_1  
anotherpart anotherpart_2   .prt    //server/folder3/anotherpart_2  
anotherpart anotherpart_3   .prt    //server/folder2/anotherpart_3  
anotherpart anotherpart_3   .cgm    //server/folder1/anotherpart_3  
anotherpart anotherpart_4   .prt    //server/folder3/anotherpart_4  
onemorepart onemorepart_1   .prt    //server/folder2/onemorepart_1  
onemorepart onemorepart_2   .prt    //server/folder1/onemorepart_2  
onemorepart onemorepart_2   .dwg    //server/folder2/onemorepart_2  
onemorepart onemorepart_3   .prt    //server/folder1/onemorepart_3  
onemorepart onemorepart_4   .prt    //server/folder1/onemorepart_4
```

A simple dataframe merge does not work, because the strings are never exact matches (it is always a substring). I also tried the following method based on other questions here on stackoverflow:

```
df_all[df_all.name.str.contains('|'.join(df_search.search))]
```

This gave me a full list of all the found items in df_all, but i don't know which search string returned which result.

I managed to get it to work with a for loop, but it is slow (67 minutes) with my dataset:

```
super_df = []
for search_item in df_search.search:
     df_entire.loc[df_entire.file.str.contains(search_item), 'search'] = search_item
     temp_df = df_entire[df_entire.file.str.contains(search_item)]
super_df = pd.concat(super_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Is it possible to do this with vectorisation to improve performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) + [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
pat = "|".join(df_search.SEARCH)
df_all.insert(0, 'SEARCH', df_all['FILE'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False))
print (df_all)
         SEARCH           FILE EXTENSION                            PATH
0         part1        part1_1      .prt        //server/folder1/part1_1
1         part1        part1_2      .prt        //server/folder2/part1_2
2         part1        part1_2      .pdf        //server/folder3/part1_2
3         part1        part1_3      .prt        //server/folder2/part1_3
4   anotherpart  anotherpart_1      .prt  //server/folder1/anotherpart_1
5   anotherpart  anotherpart_2      .prt  //server/folder3/anotherpart_2
6   anotherpart  anotherpart_3      .prt  //server/folder2/anotherpart_3
7   anotherpart  anotherpart_3      .cgm  //server/folder1/anotherpart_3
8   anotherpart  anotherpart_4      .prt  //server/folder3/anotherpart_4
9   onemorepart  onemorepart_1      .prt  //server/folder2/onemorepart_1
10  onemorepart  onemorepart_2      .prt  //server/folder1/onemorepart_2
11  onemorepart  onemorepart_2      .dwg  //server/folder2/onemorepart_2
12  onemorepart  onemorepart_3      .prt  //server/folder1/onemorepart_3
13  onemorepart  onemorepart_4      .prt  //server/folder1/onemorepart_4
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I was having a problem with the insert, and realised it was because one of my search items had a '()' character in it, which was giving me two groups in the regex. I also filtered out all of the NaN values after this, as some files didn't match. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, it raises an error for my data: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 12, placement implies 1`. Do you know how to deal with it?

Comment: @ahbon - Hard question, one idea should be use `pat = "|".join([re.escape(x) for x in df_search.SEARCH])` if possible some special chars in column - escape values

Answer (score 1):

I will do it in this way:

```
df_all['SEARCH'] = ''
for val in df_search.SEARCH:
    df_all.loc[df_all['FILE'].str.match(val), 'SEARCH'] = val
```