# Perform a merge based on a substring match?

Tags: python, string, performance, pandas, merge

While this question is closely related to [Fuzzy Match Merge with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas), this question is specifically about merging **only** (or subsetting, in this case) when the key in one `DataFrame` is a full match, or substring of the key in another `DataFrame`. To illustrate my point, here are 2 `DataFrames`:

```
df1
   id   code
0   1   E282
1   2  O0080
2   3    R52
3   4  J0100
4   5    F99

df2
    code  val
0   V282   11
1   O008   12
2  J0101   13
3    F99   14
4    R55   15
```

The problem with using `difflib` is that I really don't want to match the closest string, and I'm not sure I'd be able to separate matches like `V282` to `E282`, which shouldn't happen and a match like `O008` to `O0080` which should merge.

The expected output should be

```
   code1  id
0  O0080   2
1    F99   5
```

I can get to this result with

```
import numpy as np
df1[np.logical_or.reduce([df1['code'].str.contains(code) for code in df2.code.tolist()])]
```

but since `df1` is 42M rows long and `df2` contains ~4000 codes, this method is unbelievably slow. Is this the best I'm going to do? It just seems unfortunate, when inner merging a 21M row df and a 7M row df on exact keys takes < 1 minute.

Comment: Will the `df1` code always start with the `df2` code - The extra characters always at the end?

Comment: Yup, the extra characters will always be at the end.

Comment: Oh did the answer work? How long did it take? I'm curious.

Comment: @coldspeed yeah it definitely sped it up. It only takes like 15% the time now, which is manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult problem. Maybe consider a python approach? `any` will shortcircuit here, so you should save on some cycles. Also, `contains` does not necessarily check from the beginning, so using `startswith` instead should be more efficient.

```
df1[
    any(
         i.startswith(j) for j in df2.codes.tolist()
    ) for i in df1.codes.tolist()
]
```

Comment: If you run into memory issues, remove the `.tolist` calls, but that'll result in some performance drop.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'code':['E282', 'O0080', 'R52', 'J0100', 'F99']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code':['V282','O008','J0101','F99','R55'], 'val':[11,12, 13, 14, 15]})

pat = "|".join(df2['code'])
df1.insert(0, 'part_code', df1['code'].str.extract("(" + pat + ')', expand=False))
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='part_code', right_on='code')[['code_y', 'id']]
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/48744202/12256369