# How to assign category based on contained string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data as shown below:

[image]

I have a reference table shown below:

[image]

I want to loop through data table's "Description" to see if the string contains each word in reference table "Key" column, if so, I will enter corresponding category in reference table's column "Category" to data table's "Category" column. Both tables are Dataframe.

I am able to assign value to the data based on one key:

```
k = 'apple'
ind=df[df['Description'].str.contains(k)].index
df.loc[ind,'Category'] = 'A'
```

If I want to loop through the reference table "Key" column, should I convert the reference table to dictionary or just set key column as index? How should I loop it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas - Merge based on substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743662/python-pandas-merge-based-on-substring-in-string)

Comment: Can you please give a sample dataframe?

Comment: Hi G.Anderson, awesome codes, however, I have a problem with my data, in description, the sentence can contain 2 or more words. For example, it can be "I went to dance and got honey", so i want to loop through it and make the later loop correct the prior one