# join/merge pandas dataframes where index is substring of other index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I would like to join (or merge) 2 dataframes where the index of the second dataframe is a substring of the one of the first dataframe.
I could do it by creating a temporary column that is a substring of the index and then join on this column, but I'm sure there's another more intelligent way to do it.

df1:

```
XX0001S1    4
XX0001S2    4.5
XX0001S3    4
XX0253S1    13
XX0254S3    5
```

df2

```
XX0001  good
XX0253  bad
XX0254  average
```

result should be:

```
XX0001S1    4   good
XX0001S2    4.5 good
XX0001S3    4   good
XX0253S1    13  bad
XX0254S3    5   average
```

Any ideas please?

M.

Comment: Hi, I don't think there is a better way, than temporarily creating a column. What is wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Important**: This solution may fail if [regex-reserved characters](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) were present in the short index.

Explicit creation of a new column can be avoided by using [string accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str) as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48744231/3218693). Just map the short index found onto the corresponding text values.

**Data**

Names were assigned to sample data columns for convenience. Just replace them with the actual ones.

```
df
Out[75]:
          val1
XX0001S1   4.0
XX0001S2   4.5
XX0001S3   4.0
XX0253S1  13.0
XX0254S3   5.0

df2
Out[77]:
           text
XX0001     good
XX0253      bad
XX0254  average
```

**Code**

The solution can be put into an one-liner. I wrote it separately for clarity.

```
# 1. regex search pattern at string beginning
patt = "^(" + "|".join(df2.index.values) + ")"

# 2. find corresponding substrings via accessor
idx2_values = df.index.str.extract(patt, expand=False)

# 3.map index to the contents
df["text"] = df2.loc[idx2_values, "text"].values

# result
df
Out[108]: 
          val1     text
XX0001S1   4.0     good
XX0001S2   4.5     good
XX0001S3   4.0     good
XX0253S1  13.0      bad
XX0254S3   5.0  average
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response!