# How to use the contain function in the columns of the first df to filter with the columns of the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, contains

1. I have two dataframes, main df and index df.
2. The target I want to do is let the column `product` of main df can use
   'contain' function in index df to filter key word.
3. In the end, the main df can have new a column `keyword` to show
   `main_df[keyword]=[C2,VA,E220F,7350M]`.

main df is

```
        data    num           product
 0  2019-10-01  39013000    xxxxxC2xxxxxxx
 1  2019-10-01  39013000    xxxxxxVAxxxxxxxxxxxx
 2  2019-10-28  39013000    xxxxxxxxE220Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 3  2019-12-31  39013000    xxxxxxxx7350Mxxxxxxxx
```

index df is

```
    product
0   VA
1   C2
2   7350M
3   E220F
```

My code is:

```py
for key in key_word:
    mask = df_import_tmp0["product"].str.contains(key) 
df_import_tmp0['keyword']=key
```

The output is not what I want:

df_import_tmp0

```
    data         num            product                 keyword
0   2019-10-01  39013000    xxxxxC2xxxxxxx              E220F
1   2019-10-01  39013000    xxxxxxVAxxxxxxxxxxxx        E220F
2   2019-10-28  39013000    xxxxxxxxE220Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx  E220F
3   2019-12-31  39013000    xxxxxxxx7350Mxxxxxxxx       E220F
```

Comment: what is `key_word`? what is your desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas - Merge based on substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743662/python-pandas-merge-based-on-substring-in-string)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you're asking:

```py
df['keyword'] = df['product'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(idx['product'].tolist()) + ')')
```

Input:

```
df:

         data       num                     product
0  2019-10-01  39013000              xxxxxC2xxxxxxx
1  2019-10-01  39013000        xxxxxxVAxxxxxxxxxxxx
2  2019-10-28  39013000  xxxxxxxxE220Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3  2019-12-31  39013000       xxxxxxxx7350Mxxxxxxxx

idx:

  product
0      VA
1      C2
2   7350M
3   E220F
```

Output:

```
         data       num                     product keyword
0  2019-10-01  39013000              xxxxxC2xxxxxxx      C2
1  2019-10-01  39013000        xxxxxxVAxxxxxxxxxxxx      VA
2  2019-10-28  39013000  xxxxxxxxE220Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx   E220F
3  2019-12-31  39013000       xxxxxxxx7350Mxxxxxxxx   7350M
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
import numpy as np    
df = pd.DataFrame({"product": product_list})
    key_words = ['VA','C2','7350M','E220F']
    df["keyword"] = ''
    for kw in key_words:
        df['keyword'][df["product"].replace(np.nan,'').str.contains(kw)] = kw
```

Gives:

```
    product                     keyword
0   xxxxxC2xxxxxxx              C2
1   xxxxxxVAxxxxxxxxxxxx        VA
2   xxxxxxxxE220Fxxxxxxxxxxxxx  E220F
3   xxxxxxxx7350Mxxxxxxxx       7350M
```

Comment: It can work!!!  BUT,I want also ask if the product is vacancy, I run this code would show error code "Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values" .  How can I solve this error. txs

Comment: I edited the code above to deal with np.nan values

Comment: thanks u a lot .it can work fluent!!!