# merging df in pandas based on "contains" values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs

df_1

```
Nº.do Incidente Status  Description Per_Extracao
0   IN6948271   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_SASG_GD9822...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
1   IN6948304   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_AACE_R4539 ...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
2   IN6948307   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
3   IN6948309   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
4   IN6948310   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
5   IN6948311   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
```

df_2

```
    JOB_NAME    JOB_STREAM_NAME
0   PP_AACD_NR_D8706_TIHIBRIDA_PROC_EXCUC_D P26_AACD_FAC_TOD
1   PP_SASG_GD9822  P26_AACE_U08
2   PP_AACE_R4539   P26_AACE_U09
3   PP_AACE_R4539_CONS_JUNC P26_AACE_U08
4   PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_01    P26_AACE_U08
5   PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_02    P26_AACE_U08
```

I'm trying to merge then based on the value of JOB_NAME in df_2

the output should be something like this

merged_df

```
Nº.do Incidente Status  Description Per_Extracao JOB_NAME    JOB_STREAM_NAME
0   IN6948271   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_SASG_GD9822...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08 PP_SASG_GD9822  P26_AACE_U08
1   IN6948304   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_AACE_R4539 ...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08 PP_AACE_R4539   P26_AACE_U09
```

its not a regular join, its a contains contains condition("JOB_NAME" value in df_2 founded in "Description" column of df_1).

could you guys help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48744231/15521392) answer we can merge your dfs with some little changes.

```
pat = "|".join(map(str, df2['JOB_NAME']))
df1.insert(0, 'merge_key', df1['Description'].str.extract("("+pat+")", expand=False))

df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='merge_key', right_on='JOB_NAME').drop('merge_key', axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
       Nº.do Incidente Status                                  Description  jobName                      Per_Extracao        JOB_NAME JOB_STREAM_NAME
0  ENCERRADO             GR26  D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_SASG_GD9822...      NaN  DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08  PP_SASG_GD9822    P26_AACE_U08
1  ENCERRADO             GR26  D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_AACE_R4539 ...      NaN  DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08   PP_AACE_R4539    P26_AACE_U09
```

Explanation:

The variable pat contains one big string with all jobnames we are searching for, seperated by `|`.

Then we insert a new column called `merge_key` at the 1st position (which doesn't really matter here, it could also be the last column) with [`str.extraxt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), which searchs in the column `df1['description']` in every row, if there is a match with any name of all job names in `pat` and if there is a match, it adds that match to the new column (we seperated them with `|` because in regex the `|` stands for `or`, the `()` are needed to make it caputered groups (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) for more details on regular expressions.

With the new column we can merge them two df on `merge_key` and `JOB_NAME`
At the end we drop that column `merge_key` since we only needed it for the merging.

Comment: hey @Rabinzel, thanks for your reply, I got the error:

TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-6fc170f6e97f> in <module>
----> 1 pat = "|".join(jobNameList_df_2['JOB_NAME'])
      2 dados_df_2.insert(0, 'merge_key', dados_df_2['Breve Descrição'].str.extract("("+pat+")", expand=False))
      3 
      4 df_final = dados_df_2.merge(jobNameList_df_2, left_on='merge_key', right_on='JOB_NAME').drop('merge_key', axis=1)

TypeError: sequence item 1353: expected str instance, float found

Comment: consider 
dados_df_2 in my comment as df_1 in my post
jobNameList_df_2 as df_2 in my post
column 'Breve Descrição' as description

Comment: I'll update my answer where all the values of the job name get joined together to the variable `pat`. See if it works now

Comment: I believe I need to convert the JOB_NAME column to string :

I'm trying the 2 options below and none are working:

jobNameList_df_2['JOB_NAME'] = jobNameList_df_2['JOB_NAME'].astype(str)
jobNameList_df_2['JOB_NAME'] = jobNameList_df_2['JOB_NAME'].map(str)

Comment: check my answer again. If that doesn't work, please print the whole column of job name and copy paste the data to your question with [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73450488/edit)

Comment: that worked @Rabnzel, really thanks, but, just for me be able to understand, would you mind to explain what exactly the code is doing? I mean :

pat = "|".join(map(str, df2['JOB_NAME'])) -> here, are you creating a list of the values present in the JOB_NAME column spplited by "|"?

df1.insert(0, 'merge_key', df1['Description'].str.extract("("+pat+")", expand=False)) - and here?

df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='merge_key', right_on='JOB_NAME').drop('merge_key', axis=1) -  here you are doing the merge, what does mean the .drop('merge_key', axis=1)?

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

**The easiest way is:**

**- Imagine this is your first csv file ::**

[image]

- **and this is second csv file ::**

[image]

So as you can see these 2 data is like yours on pattern , there are only 2 rows on `Sensor_2` column that are equal to the other file . ( check 1st and 2nd row on both tables)

now what we can do is :

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.read_excel("myData1.xlsx")
df1.head()

df2 = pd.read_excel("myData2.xlsx")
df2.head()

df_merged = df1.merge(df2,on=["Sensor_2"],suffixes=('', '_drop'))
df_merged.drop([col for col in df_merged.columns if 'drop' in col], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df_merged.head())
```

and the result is :

```
   Sensor_1  Sensor_2  Sensor_3  Year
0        10         1       1.5  2020
1        11         2       2.0  2020
```

Comment: You did a nice effort explaining your approach, but that is not what the OP is searching for. In his data, there is no exact match between the 2 df's. He needs some way to check if a substring in one df is in the string on the other df. That's why `pd.merge` isn't possible right away.

Comment: as @Rabinzel said, I don't have exac match between the 1 dfs, this solution is good, but not what I'm looking for