# merging 2 dfs in 1("left join") in pandas based on "contains" values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dfs

df_1

```
Nº.do Incidente Status  Description Per_Extracao
0   IN6948271   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_SASG_GD9822...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
1   IN6948304   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_AACE_R4539 ...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
2   IN6948307   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
3   IN6948309   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
4   IN6948310   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
5   IN6948311   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_ADAT_SPRK_EX...   DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08
```

df_2

```
    JOB_NAME    JOB_STREAM_NAME
0   PP_AACD_NR_D8706_TIHIBRIDA_PROC_EXCUC_D P26_AACD_FAC_TOD
1   PP_SASG_GD9822  P26_AACE_U08
2   PP_AACE_R4539   P26_AACE_U09
3   PP_AACE_R4539_CONS_JUNC P26_AACE_U08
4   PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_01    P26_AACE_U08
5   PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_02    P26_AACE_U08
```

I'm trying to merge then based on the value of JOB_NAME in df_2 founded in df_1(Description columns), it's a kind of a left join on sql, because I need everything from df_2

the output should be something like this

merged_df

```
Nº.do Incidente Status  Description Per_Extracao JOB_NAME JOB_STREAM_NAME
0   IN6948271   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_SASG_GD9822...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08 PP_SASG_GD9822  P26_AACE_U08
1   IN6948304   ENCERRADO   GR26 D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_AACE_R4539 ...    DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08 PP_AACE_R4539 P26_AACE_U09
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN PP_AACD_NR_D8706_TIHIBRIDA_PROC_EXCUC_D   P26_AACD_FAC_TOD
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN PP_AACE_R4539_CONS_JUNC P26_AACE_U08
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_01 P26_AACE_U08 
5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_02 P26_AACE_U08
```

tried to use some merge commands, but, none has worked, for example:

```
df_test = df_2.merge(df_2,left_on='JOB_NAME',right_on=df_1['Description'].str.extract(df_2['JOB_NAME']),how='left')
```

and

```
df_test = df_2.merge(df_2,left_on='JOB_NAME',right_on=df_1['Description'].str.contains(df_2['JOB_NAME']),how='left')
```

Comment: I already posted you the solution for this few days ago, is there something wrong with it or why do you ask the same question again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merging df in pandas based on "contains" values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450488/merging-df-in-pandas-based-on-contains-values)

Comment: hey man, I aprecciate your help there, but, this time, it's not the same thing, if you have a look in this post, I'm trying a "left" join, not a "inner" join...would you be able to help me again on this?

Comment: oh, then I was a little fast on this, sorry. It just looked exactly the same :D. I will have another look

Comment: @Rabinzel because it's the same data...:), but a different situation\resolution that I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same answer as in the other question, just add the keyword `right` to it on how the merge should be done.

```
pat = "|".join(df2['JOB_NAME'])
df1.insert(0, 'merge_key', df1['Description'].str.extract("("+pat+")", expand=False))

df = df1.merge(df2, how='right', left_on='merge_key', right_on='JOB_NAME').drop('merge_key', axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
       Nº.do Incidente Status                                  Description  jobName                      Per_Extracao                                 JOB_NAME   JOB_STREAM_NAME
0        NaN              NaN                                          NaN      NaN                               NaN  PP_AACD_NR_D8706_TIHIBRIDA_PROC_EXCUC_D  P26_AACD_FAC_TOD
1  ENCERRADO             GR26  D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_SASG_GD9822...      NaN  DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08                           PP_SASG_GD9822      P26_AACE_U08
2  ENCERRADO             GR26  D.I.T.I. >>> ABEND NO JOB PP_AACE_R4539 ...      NaN  DE : 2022/01/05 ATÉ : 2022/12/08                            PP_AACE_R4539      P26_AACE_U09
3        NaN              NaN                                          NaN      NaN                               NaN                  PP_AACE_R4539_CONS_JUNC      P26_AACE_U08
4        NaN              NaN                                          NaN      NaN                               NaN                 PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_01      P26_AACE_U08
5        NaN              NaN                                          NaN      NaN                               NaN                 PP_AACE_R4539_FMRC_TD_02      P26_AACE_U08
```

Comment: the only thing @Rabinzel in this case is this:
df1.insert(0, 'merge_key', df1['Description'].str.extract("("+pat+")", expand=False))

If I have a value in "pat" that doesnt have a match in the "Description" column, it won't bring that value to the merged df.

and I need everything from pat not from the match in that piece of code.

Comment: thats not true, see your desired output and mine, it is the same. When we insert the column, everywhere where no match was found will be a `NaN`. Then we merge df1 with df2 but this time we use `how='right'`, which means every row of df2 will be in the result, no matter if there is a match or not. Have a look at [merge101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101), and see what it means to have left, right, inner or outer merge.

Comment: yes, because there it's just a sample of my dataset, let me give a sample:

if we have in pat the joName = AAAAAA

and we don't have any value in the Description column with this, that means that the jobName AAAAAA won't be inserted in the df1 because there weren't match, right?

Comment: If you merge df1 with df2 and do a right merge, no matter what matches or not, every row of df2 will be in the result. if you do a left merge, every row of df1 will be in the result. in an inner merge, only the rows gets displayed were df1 and df2 have a match.

Comment: if we have a jobname with `AAAA` and we don't have it in the description, then this row will still be in the final output, just as `NaN`

Comment: considering you last comment, in the final output the jobName value would be NaN for the jobName AAAA or the rest of the row? sorry, didn't get this part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247566/discussion-between-gfernandes-and-rabinzel).